# Error at line 3: PL/SQL: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I write a sql script in oracle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TIPUSUPDATE
AFTER UPDATE OF RENDSZAM, MODELL
ON AUTO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE TIPUS
    SET TIPUS.RENDSZAM = :NEW.RENDSZAM,
    SET TIPUS.MODELL = :NEW.MODELL
    WHERE TIPUS.RENDSZAM = :OLD.RENDSZAM
    AND TIPUS.MODELL = :OLD.MODELL;
END;
```

I created the tables, but when i run this script i got a error message:

> Error at line 3: PL/SQL: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification.

Somebody can help me pls?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you can't have 2 `set` clauses in an `update` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with following and it is working. Like mentioned earlier by sstan, you can not have 2 set clauses in an update statement. Make sure the tables AUTO and TIPUS are created before you execute following

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TIPUSUPDATE
AFTER UPDATE OF RENDSZAM, MODELL ON AUTO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE TIPUS
SET TIPUS.RENDSZAM = :NEW.RENDSZAM,
TIPUS.MODELL = :NEW.MODELL
WHERE TIPUS.RENDSZAM = :OLD.RENDSZAM
AND TIPUS.MODELL = :OLD.MODELL;
END;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

Always remember to prefix SCHEMA NAME before calling your table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER <schema_name>.TIPUSUPDATE
AFTER UPDATE OF RENDSZAM, MODELL
ON <schema_name>.AUTO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE <schema_name>.TIPUS
    SET TIPUS.RENDSZAM = :NEW.RENDSZAM,
        TIPUS.MODELL = :NEW.MODELL
    WHERE TIPUS.RENDSZAM = :OLD.RENDSZAM
    AND TIPUS.MODELL = :OLD.MODELL;
END;
```

Comment: why do you think it's a naming problem?